# Neo4j Java Driver Transaction Seems Not to Commit

Tags: java, neo4j, transactions

I am using Ne04j v3.1.0 with the Java driver.  I am having trouble getting the results of an update statement (cypher SET) within an explicit transaction to persist.  Returned values from within the transaction show the change, but after the transaction has ended the change seems to be gone.  I know that updates are sensitive to results processing

[http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/drivers/process-results/][1]

so I have been aggressive in my code about consuming all results and closing my sessions.

I wrote a test program to demonstrate the problem:

```
package uk.co.scapps.createdirs.neo;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.AuthTokens;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.Driver;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.GraphDatabase;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.Record;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.Session;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.StatementResult;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.Transaction;


public class Trans {
    static Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost", AuthTokens.basic("neo4j", "neo4k"));
    static Session session = driver.session();
    final static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        session = driver.session();
        StatementResult results ;
        session = driver.session();
        try (Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction()) {
            results = tx.run("MATCH (n:THING) RETURN n.name as name");
            while (results.hasNext()) {
                Record record = results.next();
                System.out.println("in the txn before the update: " + record.get("name").toString());
            }           
            results.consume();
            results = tx.run("MATCH (n:THING {name: 'a'}) SET n.name = 'asdasd' RETURN n.name as name");
            while (results.hasNext()) {
                Record record = results.next();
                System.out.println("results returned from the update: " + record.get("name").toString());
            }           
            results.consume();
            results = tx.run("MATCH (n:THING) RETURN n.name as name");
            while (results.hasNext()) {
                Record record = results.next();
                System.out.println("after the update but still in the txn: " + record.get("name").toString());
            }           
            results.consume();
            tx.close();
            session.close();
        }
        session = driver.session();
        results = session.run("MATCH (n:THING) RETURN n.name as name");
        while (results.hasNext()) {
            Record record = results.next();
            System.out.println("after the txn: " + record.get("name").toString());
        }           
        results.consume();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
in the txn before the update: "a"
in the txn before the update: "b"
in the txn before the update: "c"
results returned from the update: "asdasd"
after the update but still in the txn: "asdasd"
after the update but still in the txn: "b"
after the update but still in the txn: "c"
after the txn: "a"
after the txn: "b"
after the txn: "c"
```

I haven't included the code, but I wrote a non-transactional (implicit transactional) version of the program and it works as expected.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had failed to execute `txn.success()`.

Comment: You may want to consider deleting the question, or accepting your own answer.